# How to set max date of the kendo Date picker in Kendo Grid by using jquery?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datepicker, kendo-datetimepicker

I want to set the Maximum date for Kendo Date picker in Grid.

I've a column with type "date", so i want to set maximum date for the Datepicker for that column.

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/rangeselection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define the schema on the dataSource your grid is bound to, just add in the validation for the date column

```
validation: { max: new Date('12/1/2006') }
```

See sample http://jsbin.com/quyoto/1/edit?html,js,output